# Removing items from Collection Taking too much time in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have 89 millions records, here I want to delete selected documents. But it is talking too much time to remove the document. I have the same code values in the collections.
I am using `db.document.remove({code : '789456'})`
I have tried the script in the mongo shell. Need to find better ways to do that? any simplified queries?

Comment: Well if there is no index on the "code" field then the database needs to scan though *"89 million records"*, to see if the value matches anything. Nothing is free. Index the field  ( taking more space as nothing is free ) for faster results.

Comment: Also, the title is misleading. Removing _collection_ is super-fast.